# ADT Eclipse - automatically close all project related editors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Is there is any way to close all files opened when closing a project in ADT Eclipse?

If I close a project, the editors (files opened) of that project remains open but the content is 'offline'. Then I have to manually close all editors to clean the tab list.

With netbeans7+, this is a default action.

Thanks.

Comment: you can right click on one tab and chose close all, but that may close other tabs that you want to keep open?

Comment: @icrovett With this option, I close all other files of other projects too, but I want to keep only the files opened by other projects.